# What is the LoggingSession buffer size?

Tags: logging, windows-runtime, uwp

I am using [LoggingSession](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/windows.foundation.diagnostics.loggingsession) for tracing in a universal app.
LoggingSession uses an in-memory circular buffer to cache messages.
What is the size this buffer? Can/should one configure it?

The max size of the .etl file created via SaveToFileAsync() seems to be 3KB.
Oberving the directory in file explorer strangely shows .etl.tmp files with size 260KB being created and deleted.

Comment: It does not appear there is anyway to adjust the buffer size

Answer (score 1):

LoggingSession uses 4 buffers. The buffer size is either 64KB or 65KB, depending on the version of Windows. The sizes are not configurable. The idea is that your program continually logs info about what it is doing. Then if something weird happens (i.e. unexpected exception) you can save the most recent 256KB worth of logs and upload them.

While the raw buffers total up to 256KB or 260KB, if you haven't logged any events, they'll be mostly empty. The LoggingSession will flush the data to disk, then run the raw data through compression, which is why the final size is very small. It would be bigger if there were more data in the buffers.